# Using jquery to slide in content horizontally

Tags: jquery

I have a few links on a page which refers to some content divs on the same page. I'm trying to create a very simple horizontal sliding effect to sliding effect to show the content. For example, initially only box1 content should be visible, and when clicked on link2, the box2 content shold slide in.

```
<a href="#box1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#box2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#box3">Link 3</a>

<div class="content">
    <div id="box1">..</div>
    <div id="box2">..</div>
    <div id="box3">..</div>
</div>
```

Please have a look at the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/G9eVf/

Comment: Your question is not requiring an answer, but someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/3Vrh9/4/

Making use of this plugin

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Plugin source:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js